# How to relate images in a folder to its metadata stored in mysql in perl?

Tags: java, mysql, perl, metadata

I am able to store the uploaded image in a folder(named by its category) and its related data like the uploaders info,its category in mysql using the code below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
use CGI;
$query = new CGI;
$uploader_name = $query->param("name");
$filename = $query->param("file");
$category = $query->param("cat");
$uploaded_dir = $category;
print $query->header();
$filename =~ s/.*[\/\\](.*)/$1/;
$filename =~ s/ /_/g;
$upload_filehandle = $query->upload("file");
$directory_filename = "$upload_dir/$filename";

# upload the file to the server

open UPLOADFILE, ">$directory_filename";
binmode UPLOADFILE;

while ( <$upload_filehandle> )
  {
   print UPLOADFILE;
  }

close UPLOADFILE;

# Open the file
# open MYFILE, $directory_filename || print "Cannot open file";
# my $blob_file;

# Read in the contents
# while (<MYFILE>) 
#  {
#   $blob_file .= $_;
#  }
# close MYFILE;

# make the database connection
my $dbh=DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=pics;host=localhost","?","?");
# set the value of your SQL query
$query = "insert into pic(uploader_name, category) values (?, ?) ";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute($uploader_name, $category) || print "Can't access database";

$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

I need the remaining metadata like its color, title etc of the loaded images.How can it be done? I heard of metadata extractors(in java) for this.How do they work. Suggest the best of them. 
Moreover how to relate an image with its respective metadata for retrieval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make "filename" a column in the DB table, and then you can find the rest of the data by file name.